# Check if a dispatch queue cannot keep up with tasks and is backlogged

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, ios9, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using a serial dispatch queue to alter images coming from the camera for a timelapse video app. So far I'm using GCD to offload image processing to a second thread.

I expect the app to be running for a long time and don't want to somehow overwhelm the device with processing requests.

**Is there a way to check if the dispatch queue cannot keep up with the number of operations added to it (creating a backlog)?**

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    __block UIImage* backupImage = self.thermalImage;
    backupImage = [self imageByDrawingCircleOnImage:backupImage];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.thermalImageView setImage:backupImage];
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use `NSOperationQueue` instead. Set it up as a serial queue. Then you can query how many operations are queued up.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: I have not used semaphores in ages, so I was hoping for some function to check the number of dispatch requests :)

Comment: You'd have to track the requests yourself maybe using OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier before entering the queue and OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier when a block finishes in the queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a specific number of tasks you want to execute in this queue before deciding that it's backlogged? If so, use a `semaphore` to limit the number of tasks in the queue.

```
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(3);
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.foo.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

    for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            NSLog(@"hello from #%d", i);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });
    }
```

You can specify a timeout and then check the return value of `dispatch_semaphore_wait` to see if you timed out and then create a new queue or just wait until the queue frees up etc.